# Increase Production

Tags: civilization-6

I am currently in 1020AD and my city production is around 13-24 per city.  I know you can build an industrial complex and maybe I should have built more mines but I was trying to save space for districts plus, since I have low production, it is hard to produce builders.   So in Civ 6 what are some key factors to consider to up production in your cities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mines and Industrial  Complexes (IC) are the best ways to increase production, especially the IC, since you can keep upgrading it with new production buildings throughout the game. Make sure to position your IC adjacent  to mines too, because each adjacent mine gives the IC +1 Production (and this bonus can be increased with Social Policies).

Amenities factor into your production as well. As [stated in the Civilopedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FNuG.jpg), having enough Amenities to have your citizens be either *Happy* or *Ecstatic* will increase your production by 5% and 10% respectively. Having too few will actually result in a decrease in production as well, so at the very least you need to make sure you always have the minimum number of Amenities to keep your cities at the *Content* level.

Finally, one last note, is that you shouldn't worry about building too many mines (or any other worker created tile improvement). You can tear down any tile improvements later on if you suddenly have the need for that tile hosting a mine. The same doesn't apply to buildings you construct directly from your city, though.